# Safari loading Document object instead of data with jQuery $.get method, resulting in HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

**EDIT: I basically got things down to the fact that is necessary to use the file:// protocol to reproduce this. Also, I had Chrome launched with --allow-file-access-from-files flag. I am now using normal http protocol, so for me this question has become a bit more academic. It would be nice if it worked though, or at least someone could explain me what is going on.**

Consider the following HTML (in the file "a.html"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <article id="article-id">
        <h3 class="entry-title">
            Title-h3
        </h3>
        <div class="entry-content">
        </div>
    </article>  
 </body>
</html>
```

And I am trying to load the first child of the #article-id tag from another file (say index.html) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

$.get('a.html', function() {
    return function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        var lTitle = jQuery("<div>").append(data)
                    .find("#article-id :first-child").html().trim();
        alert(lTitle);
    }
}());
```

In Safari 5.1.3, the first alert gives "[ object Document ]" and the next jQuery-statement throws a HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR.

In Chrome 19.0.1084.54 this seems to work as expected, and I get the loaded data in the first alert, and "Title-h3" in the second alert.

Is this a bug in jQuery or am I doing something wrong?

Weird extra bit of information: if you add

```
<iframe width="500" height="369" src="http://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

inside the div, Safari works as Chrome.

Comment: @Esailiza what do you mean by again

Comment: Have you tried `var lTitle = data.find("#article-id :first-child").html().trim();`. You cannot put html and such tags inside a div.

Comment: Now I did. "undefined is not a function", Safari complains about that. Chrome does with a similar error.

Comment: Try `$(data).find("#article-id :first-child").html().trim()`

Comment: Flambino, In Safari: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'elem.innerHTML.replace')